# Trying to write a method to create an array list

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist, methods, listbox

I'm using Netbeans/GUI to make a fantasy basketball game program. I'm trying to create methods that create arraylists, that way I can call the method for the array every time I need it for one of my button events, rather than recode the array under each individual event. The array list method loads up data for the team name from a listbox I created in the design window. Code is as follows:

```
public class JFMarchMadness extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public JFMarchMadness() 
    {
        initComponents();
    }

    //creates arraylist and loads up data from arraylist of type string (lstConfTeams)
    void createCTArrayList ()
    {
        ArrayList<BasketballTeam> alCTeams=new ArrayList <>();

        String CTteamName;
        String CTstatus="";
        int CTwins=0;
        int CTlosses=0;
        double CTwinLossPct=0;

        for (int iCount = 0; iCount <lstConfTeams.getModel().getSize(); iCount++)
        {
            CTteamName=lstConfTeams.getModel().getElementAt(iCount);
            alCTeams.add(new BasketballTeam(CTstatus,CTteamName,CTwins,CTlosses,CTwinLossPct));
        }

    }

    private void btnPlayMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    // call createCTArrayList method and begin for loop


        createCTArrayList ();

        int iCTCount;

        for (iCTCount=0; iCTCount<alCTeams.size; iCTCount++){
        //
        }
    }
```

Right now it gets an error where it can't find the arraylist: alCTeams when I try to call it in the for loop statement. Did I write the method incorrectly or am I calling it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration for `alCTeams` should be located under the `class` not the `method`.

Like this:

```
public class JFMarchMadness extends javax.swing.JFrame {

ArrayList<BasketballTeam> alCTeams=new ArrayList <>();

public JFMarchMadness() 
{
    initComponents();
}

//creates arraylist and loads up data from arraylist of type string (lstConfTeams)
void createCTArrayList ()
{
    String CTteamName;
    String CTstatus="";
    int CTwins=0;
    int CTlosses=0;
    double CTwinLossPct=0;

    for (int iCount = 0; iCount <lstConfTeams.getModel().getSize(); iCount++)
    {
        CTteamName=lstConfTeams.getModel().getElementAt(iCount);
        alCTeams.add(new BasketballTeam(CTstatus,CTteamName,CTwins,CTlosses,CTwinLossPct));
    }

}

private void btnPlayMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
// call createCTArrayList method and begin for loop


    createCTArrayList ();

    int iCTCount;

    for (iCTCount=0; iCTCount<alCTeams.size; iCTCount++){
    //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `alCTeams` to be visible to other methods then it should be a class member rather than a local variable.

Comment: Also, there is no declaration for 'lstConfTeams', the variable names are confusing and reveal implementation through unnecessary prefixes, the names do not conform to the Java naming conventions, and you aren't using the Event Dispatch Thread, which means some of your GUI actions probably will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared alCTeams in the btnPlayMouseClicked method. You can pass instance ogf the object by returning it from createCTArrayList

```
public class JFMarchMadness extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public JFMarchMadness() 
    {
        initComponents();
    }

    //creates arraylist and loads up data from arraylist of type string (lstConfTeams)
    ArrayList<BasketballTeam> createCTArrayList ()
    {
        ArrayList<BasketballTeam> alCTeams=new ArrayList <>();

        String CTteamName;
        String CTstatus="";
        int CTwins=0;
        int CTlosses=0;
        double CTwinLossPct=0;

        for (int iCount = 0; iCount <lstConfTeams.getModel().getSize(); iCount++)
        {
            CTteamName=lstConfTeams.getModel().getElementAt(iCount);
            alCTeams.add(new BasketballTeam(CTstatus,CTteamName,CTwins,CTlosses,CTwinLossPct));
        }
        return alCTeams;
    }

    private void btnPlayMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    // call createCTArrayList method and begin for loop


        ArrayList<BasketballTeam> alCTeams = createCTArrayList ();

        int iCTCount;

        for (iCTCount=0; iCTCount<alCTeams.size; iCTCount++){
        //
        }
    }
```